# Ionic: Manipulate the GET request result retrieved via REST API handler of the IonicSuper starter template

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, rxjs, ionic3

I'm having problems manipulating the resulting elements of a GET request.

The app is being built using the [IonicSuper starter template](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/super) and uses the [REST API handler](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/blob/master/ionic-angular/official/super/src/providers/api/api.ts) shipped within that template.

I seemingly fail to understand what the type of the returned result is and how I can manipulate it. I gotta say, that I do not have much experience with app development, let alone TypeScript and its variants. But what I understand is that RxJS provides an Observable data type, that allows [certain operations on the resulting data](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/observables_array_operations.html). But these do not work, when I'm using said API handler.
I have searched on various sites for solutions, but none was fitting. Everywhere I looked, the basic Angular HttpClient was used in conjunction with the RxJS Observable. Since I'm using the IonicSuper template, I'd like to use the included REST API handler, as well. But I'm not able to retrieve the information I need from its code and documentation.

My goal is to get a single object (or alternatively: an array containing only one object) from a set of objects, specified by a given id. Here's are the relevant parts of my provider.ts:

```
import { Injectable }   from '@angular/core';

import { Api }                      from '../api/api';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

import { tPrediction }              from '../../models/prediction';

@Injectable()
export class Prediction {
    //API endpoint: Predictions
    private epPredictions = 'predictions';

    constructor(private api: Api) { }

    getPrediction(id: number) {
        let seq = this.api
            .get(this.epPredictions)
//          .flatMap((response) => response.json())
            .filter(prediction => prediction.id == id)
            .share();

        seq.subscribe((res: any) => {
            console.debug('prediction id', id);
            console.debug('res', res);
        }, err => {
            this.handleError(err);
        });
        return seq;
    }
}
```

Now, both, flatMap() and filter(), yield the TypeScript error `Property '(flatMap|filter)' does not exist on type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>'.`

And here is where I'm lost: I understand it that way, that http.get() returns an Observable and that this should employ these operators. That's obviously not the case.

I've also tried with giving a function, similar to the [RxJS docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/where.md):

```
let seq = this.api
    .get(this.epPredictions)
    //          .flatMap((response) => response.json())
    .filter(function(prediction, idx) {
        console.debug('getPrediction id', id);
        console.debug('getPrediction prediction.id', prediction["id"]);

        return prediction["id"] == id;
    })
    .share();
```

Doesn't work, either, because `prediction["id"]` is undefined.

I have problems to understand how this **ArrayBuffer** type works and what I can do with it.

1. So my main question is: how can I access/manipulate the result? So far I've only been able to return the resulting array as a *whole*, not specific parts of it.
2. Also: what does this **share()** do? I couldn't find any reference to this in the HttpClient code.

I will edit this post, if additional information is needed.

Thanks for reading through this and for any bit of knowledge, you provide.

PS: I know that I can let server do the filtering by just giving the ID as an additional GET parameter, and that might happen eventually. But because this is a very basic problem I'm trying to understand, I wanna solve this right now, while working on my current task.

---

**Edit**

I made a project copy and updated the RxJS package to version 5.5.10 (was on 5.5.7). The provider is now working with .pipe(), but it still can't access *prediction.id* because it's dealing with an ArrayBuffer.

Here's the current getPrediction():

```
getPrediction(id: number) {
    var predictions = this.api.get(this.epPredictions);
console.debug('pipe');
    var seq = predictions.pipe(
        filter(function(prediction, i){
            console.debug('prediction', prediction);
            return prediction.id === id;
        })
    );
    seq.subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.debug('prediction id', id);
        console.debug('res', res);
    }, err => {
        this.handleError(err);
    });

    return seq;
}
```

That does not work because `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.` Same goes for using the operator with

```
filter(prediction => prediction.id === id)
```

instead. I understand that I can't get the data stored in the ArrayBuffer directly. But I'd imagine that when dealing with Observables there would already be an implementation for such an interaction, especially when trying to filter the response data based on its attributes.
Or do I have to create an own implementation for that? It sounds wrong, considering that it's possible to filter elements directly on simple one-line-evaluations. But I might misreading something here.

The response body comes as follows. Every prediction is an object.

```
[
  {
    "categories": [
      0,
      1
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo"
  },
  ...
]
```

---

**Update**

Did some further research and trial and error but I'm still not able to filter through the elements. The `ArrayBuffer` type is blocking me from any access of the elements, meaning that I can't filter them.

I tried with hard-coding the result as parsable JSON in the provider and then accessing the Observable via the filter operator:

```
var predictions = from([
    {categories:[0,1], id:1},
    {categories:[0,1], id:2},
    {categories:[0,2], id:3},
    {categories:[0,1], id:4},
    {categories:[0,1], id:5},
    {categories:[0,4], id:6},
    {categories:[0,1], id:7},
    {categories:[0,1], id:8},
    {categories:[0,1], id:9},
    {categories:[0,1], id:10},
    {categories:[0,1], id:11}
]);

var seq = predictions.pipe(
    filter(prediction => {
        //print every single prediction
        console.debug('prediction', prediction);
        return prediction;
    })
);
```

This works as expected and every object is read and treated as a single entity, which is what I want.

If I do a GET request, though, the response is stored within the `ArrayBuffer` type and that makes the behavior totally different:

```
var predictions = this.http.get('http://localhost/myApi/predictions');

var seq = predictions.pipe(
    filter(function(prediction, i){
        //the whole array is printed
        console.debug('prediction', prediction);
        console.info('i', i);
        return true;
    })
);
```

So, instead of being able to read every element *for itself* only *the whole Array* can be read/printed. This makes sense because it's an ArrayBuffer and therefore a byte stream, as far as I understood. But that makes it impossible to read each element within that Array (i.e. every Prediction Object) and apply a filter to it.

How is it possible to apply RxJS' filter() or map() methods to the contents of this ArrayBuffer? Or how can I transform this ArrayBuffer to be able to do so?

The more I try to find a solution the more I get the feeling that I *have* to filter server-side before sending the JSON response to the app. But that seems inefficient for a lot of use cases. And I can't imagine that there wouldn't exist an implementation for such a case.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot going on here, so I will try to break it down as best as I can.

**RxJS Lettable Operators (likely why it can't find your operators)**

`Property '(flatMap|filter)' does not exist on type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>` - This is likely an issue with your current version of RxJS. In more recent versions they removed these chain-able methods to take a more functional approach. Instead there is a `pipe` method that takes a series of functions to apply to the event stream. That way you only need to import what you are using -- not the whole RxJS library. See more here: https://hackernoon.com/rxjs-reduce-bundle-size-using-lettable-operators-418307295e85

Example of the new API style:

```
this.api.get(this.epPredictions, {prediction_id: id})
    .pipe(filter(prediction.id === id), share())
```

**What does `share()` do?**

`share()` is only useful if you have multiple subscribers -- you shouldn't need it here. By default, when an observable is subscribed to it will get **its own event**. That means that if your observable is subscribed too twice, that your observable may be executed twice with each subscriber getting its own event. `share()` will dispatch the same event to both subscribers and execute your observable once. In RxJS speak, that means `share()` will yield an "observable sequence that contains the elements of a sequence produced by multicasting the source sequence." https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md

**Array Buffers**

To quote Mozilla -- "The ArrayBuffer is a data type that is used to represent a generic, fixed-length binary data buffer. You can't directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer; instead, you create a typed array view or a DataView which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

In other words, an ArrayBuffer is not a standard JS array -- it is a primitive representation of some sort of data (like an image). More information is need about its contents in order answer your question appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer and the links. That already helped me understanding what I'm dealing with.
I'm still missing something, because I still can'tfilter the request results. I'll edit my question with the current status and give some information on the result data.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this problem. Tried some more solutions and tested ideas. The problem is that I can't access the contents of that `ArrayBuffer`. No solution or tutorial, I found, did help with it. Updated the question.

Comment: It sounds like you need to return something different from your back end. If the data is truly just a simple JSON array, it could be that the Content-Type in your header is incorrect. Angular should automatically parse the json and return it to you if it finds the "Content-Type: 'application/json'" header.

Comment: The header is set correctly: The response sends `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8`. The web developer tool of Firefox is able to parse the whole result as valid JSON and I can inspect the response contents with it, too.